# Enable Azure Security Center for selected VMs only?

Tags: azure, securitycenter

Across our subscriptions we have about 480 VMs. I want to leverage some of the capabilities of Security Center, but only on the VMs that host publicly facing services. This is about 120 VMs. If I enable SC it seems like it will chart $15/month/VM, which would be about ~$7k a month whereas if I only enable for the 120 it is just $1,800/month/VM.

If I enable, and then manually install the agent only on the selected VMs, will I only be charged for those with the agent running, or will I get charged for every eligible VM?

Thanks, John

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue to partially activate SC for some VMs.
I found an option of Data Collection, Auto Provision for automatic installation of the Microsoft Monitoring Agent but even though this options was "OFF", SC [indentified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi7iZ.png) a new VM on Security Center.